# How to parametrize an AutoIt script to handle cross-browser window popup titles and files?

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

My AutoIt script should upload files using a browser:

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\MWUploads\myFile.pdf")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

I'm using above script's compiled executable from Selenium WebDriver for Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoItScExecutableDir+"autoitScript.exe");
```

Depending on browser, title of upload popup window differs (for Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge it's "Open" whereas for Firefox it is "File Upload"). How can I make it work for any file path on any browser, like below?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myWinTitle, myLocator, myFileToUploadPath);
```

---

//attaching an img for more clarification, when tried as per Answer

[image]

Here is the o/p of sysOut from else block-

```
E:\AOS\src\test\resources\AutoItScripts\dynamicAutoItScript.exe File Upload 
E:\AOS\src\test\resources\FilesToUpload\Greetings.png
```

here is what happening in actual-
[image]

Comment: What myLocator should  represent? For a expresion like this : Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Open", myLocator, "C:\MWUploads\myFile.pdf");

Comment: I meant  form myLocator was- parameterizing the locator of  file path text area or the button i.e. "Edit1" or Button1. But never mind as this doesn't change hence need not be parameterized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send parameters to the autoitScript.exe.

### Cross browser differences

The Upload Window changes based on the browser:

1. Firefox -> the upload window title is: File Upload
2. Chrome and Edge -> the upload window title is: Open
3. Internet Explorer -> the upload window title is: Choose File to Upload

However these remain the same:

- The location bar (ToolbarWindow32 on windows, the one on top)
- File Name bar
- Open Button

### The AutoIt script is:

```
Sleep(500);
If $CmdLine[0] > 0 Then
   ControlFocus($CmdLine[1],"","Edit1")
   ControlSetText($CmdLine[1],"","Edit1",$CmdLine[2])
   ControlClick($CmdLine[1],"","Button1")
EndIf
```

### Parameters explained:

Sleep(500); is a half of a second wait. I encounter some issues on an old pc's with a slow HDD. As a result the upload window didn't open in time for the script to be executed. Better safe then sorry.

$CmdLine[0] contains the number of parameters sent. It will contain 0 if no parameter was sent.

$CmdLine[1] - represents the upload window title

$CmdLine[2] - represents the text sent in the File Name bar

### Usage in Java:

Firefox:  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\compiledScript.exe \"File Upload\" E:\\file.txt");`

Chrome: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\compiledScript.exe Open E:\\file.txt");`

Comment: Hi, I tried the way you've explained but didnt work). below are findings if you can help-  if (browser="firefox")  {  winTitle ="File Upload";             Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoItScExecutableDir+"autoItScript.exe"+" " +winTitle+" " +fileUploadDir+filePath);  }  with above code  its typing word "Upload" in the filename field (i.e. part of window title) but not file path. So Plz tell me correct syntax if I'm missing something.  also let me know where can I sahe detailed code  with screen captures as it not possible via comments

Comment: so the problem is that this: File Upload is like two parameters that are sent in cmd. Can you change in the else the string winTitle like this? winTitle = "\"File Upload\"";

Comment: yeahh, good catch! thanks man. It worked well but I noticed upload window is getting hanged half of the times..may not be related to your answer bt a common issue with autoIt..